# Registros únicos con fecha más actual

Tags: sql-server

¿Cómo puedo hacer una select para que me devuelva los registros con fecha más actual? (en este caso seria los registros marcados en verde). He probado de varias formas pero siempre me obliga a agrupar, entonces me saca los registros que veis pero solo quiero los verdes. ¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

Necesito todos los campos, marca, codigo, descripcion, proveedor, fecha, und, no puedo prescindir de ninguno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado un select con order by?

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Las funciones *PARTITION* y *ROW_NUMBER* creo que te pueden ayudar:

Agrupas por *MARCA* y *CODIGO* ordenando de forma descendente por *FECHA* (*PARTITION*) y cada una de las líneas de estos grupos va a quedar numeradas (*ROW_NUMBER*). De modo que solo seleccionas la primera línea de cada uno de esos grupos.

Sería algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT [MARCA]
          ,[CODIGO]
          ,[DESCRIPCION]
          ,[PROVEEDOR]
          ,[FECHA]
          ,[UND]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                         PARTITION BY [MARCA], [CODIGO]
                         ORDER BY [FECHA] DESC
                   ) AS [ROW NUMBER]
      FROM [NombreDeLaTabla]
) grupos
WHERE grupos.[ROW NUMBER] = 1
ORDER BY groups.[MARCA], groups.[CODIGO]
```